# Update all unique records (compare a field in 2 different tables)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I hope you can help me.

I would like to update all Unique records by verifying that the Project Number of one table does not exist in the other.

Currently I have the procedure below, but I get an error as the returned results are more than 2100:

**The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100.**

I have done a lot of reading and research on this issue, but am struggling to find and implement a simple solution that will work for my purposes. Please note: I am a newbie.

Any ideas how I can rewrite this to work?

```
public static void NewRecords()
{
    using (var stageContext = new StagingTableDataContext())
    {
        using (var destinationContext = new               DestinationTableDataContext())
        {
            var allProjectNames = destinationContext.THEOPTIONs.Select(u => u.NAME).ToList(); 
            var deltaList = stageContext.ProjectMasters.Where(u => !allProjectNames.Contains(u.Finance_Project_Number)).ToList();

            deltaList.ForEach(u => u.Processing_Result = 0);
            deltaList.ForEach(u => u.Processing_Result_Text = "UNIQUE");

        }
        stageContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This might not be related, but why are you nesting the usage of the two context classes? Why not open `DestinationTableDataContext`, calculate `allProjectNames` and then open `StagingTableDataContext` and update the data?

Comment: @Yacoub Massad I nested the usage of the 2 context classes to simplify the code for reuse and for support purposes.

Comment: What is the size of the `allProjectNames` list?

Comment: @Yacoub Massad it is about 15 000 - 20 000 at the moment. So it is not small...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error message because allProjectNames hold too many records to be parameterized for the second select statement. You could either fetch the entire ProjectMasters table first (see below my extra added ToList), and then query it. Or implement a stored procedure which takes a table parameter.

```
public static void NewRecords()
        {
            using (var stageContext = new StagingTableDataContext())
            {
                using (var destinationContext = new DestinationTableDataContext())
                {
                    var allProjectNames = destinationContext.THEOPTIONs.Select(u => u.NAME).ToList(); 
                    var deltaList = stageContext.ProjectMasters.ToList().Where(u => !allProjectNames.Contains(u.Finance_Project_Number)).ToList();

                    deltaList.ForEach(u => u.Processing_Result = 0);
                    deltaList.ForEach(u => u.Processing_Result_Text = "UNIQUE");

                }
                stageContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response - much appreciated. I am no longer getting my error, however, all my records were updated, and not only the unique ones. Perhaps any ideas where the problem may lie?

Comment: @onmyway The suggested code updates rows in ProjectMasters where Finance_Project_Number not exists in the THEOPTIONs table. If all records were updated, maybe the result of THEOPTIONs table is the culprit. Could it be empty?

Comment: @ lobiZoli I think I understand where my issue might be coming in. 
The sql query I run does a DISTINCT :

SELECT DISTINCT [Finance_Project_Number]
FROM [InterfaceInfor].[dbo].[ProjectMaster]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM [IMS].[dbo].[THEOPTION]  
                        WHERE [InterfaceInfor].[dbo].[ProjectMaster].[Finance_Project_Number] = [IMS].[dbo].[THEOPTION].[NAME])

And the procedure does not do a distinct... Is there a way i can add a distinct clause to the procedure?

Comment: @ lobiZoli Jip, I verified; there are 15 000 records where the Finance_Project_Number does not exists (this is also the result from my procedure - so thank you, it works :D), but only 6 000 distinct records.